# Calling a sub process after for loop is completed in python

Tags: python, for-loop, subprocess

I have `python` script like below. In this script, I am collecting `stdout` and `stderr` of the script in a file and storing in `Linux`.

In this script, I am running the function `path_finder` in a loop over `input_file` 
In this script, I am using `subprocess` to move data in `Linux` to a different location.

I want this `subprocess` call to run after finishing the `loop` but instead, it runs when the `loop` runs for the first time and when the second time the `loop` runs it throws an error which is expected. As the file is present it throws an error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import traceback
import subprocess

def path_finder(
    table,
    mysql_user,
    user,
    dir,
    ):


    day = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    month = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m')

    Linux_path = '/data/logging/{}'.format(input_file)
    New_path = '/user/{}/{}/logging/{}/{}/{}'.format(user,dir,mysql_user,month,day)

    subprocess.call(["rm", Linux_path])

    so = se = open('/data/logging/{}'.format(input_file), 'a',
                   0)

    #re-open stdout without buffering
    sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'a', 0)

    # redirect stdout and stderr to the log file opened above
    os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())

    ### CODE:

    Do something

    ### if errors the print traceback

    ### repeat the same for every table in input file

    ## Execute below statement after for loop completed

    subprocess.call(["cp", Linux_path, New_path])


if len(sys.argv) != 5:
    print 'Invalid number of args......'
    exit()

input_file = sys.argv[1]
mysql_user = sys.argv[2]
user = sys.argv[3]
dir = sys.argv[4]

input = open("{}.format(input_file)", "r")

for table in input:
    path_finder(
            table,
            mysql_user,
            user,
            dir,
            )

sc.stop()
print
```

How can I change my script so that the `sub process` call will run after the `for loop` is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what the problem is. The statement you want to execute last is currently present in the function 'path_finder' which is why it is running every time.
To make this run only once and after the for loop is finished, put the statement after it.

```
for table in input:
path_finder(
        table,
        mysql_user,
        user,
        dir,
        )
subprocess.call(["cp", Linux_path, New_path])
```

This should do it.